# Is there a better way to remove the raw pointer reference to elements stored in vector

Tags: c++, stl

```
class LargeClass
{}

void FunctionA(const LargeClass&) {}

std::vector<LargeClass> vecLargeClass; // populate vecLargeClass

const LargeClass* prev = vecLargeClass[0];
for( ... )
{
    ...
    if(...)
       prev = &vecLargeClass[i];
}
```

I need to keep a reference to an element stored inside a vector.
In order to avoid copy, I currently use a raw pointer. Or I can store an index pointing to the element.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Assume the vector is NOT modified inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you can keep a "reference" to an element in a `vector` so long as that `vector`'s iterators aren't invalidated.  That is a big caveat.

A `vector`'s iterators become invalidated when the `vector` is reallocated, which can happen any time you add elements to the `vector`.  Additionally when you `erase` an item from a `vector`, all the iterators at and beyond the point of removal are invalidated.

This is all very complicated, and better not worried about.  If you need iterators to never become invalidated (so long as you don't remove *that* item itself), a `vector` might not be the best collection for your use.  Instead, you might consider a `list`, a `map`, or other collections.  Note that each has its own set of tradeoffs.

You might not need to care about the *iterators* at all, however.  If your `vector` stored not items themselves, but pointers to the items, then even if the vector is reallocated the things the pointers point to will not move.  Going this route, of course you should use a smart pointer if possible.  On the face of it, the best one would appear to be `shared_ptr`.  So your delcaration becomes:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<LargeClass>>
```

Finally, if you really need to use a `vector` and don't want to mess with smart pointers, you might do well to not keep track of "references" to the items in the `vector`, but their index positions.  Suppose you want to keep track of the item at `vecLargeClass[3]`.  Even if you do something to invalidate iterators, the item in question will still be at index `3`.  Instead of keeping track of `interator`s or pointers to things, keep track of where they are in the `vector`.

Comment: The reason why you prefer to using `std::vector<shared_ptr<LargeClass>>` is that the copy operation inside vector will be faster than that of `std::vector<LargeClass>` since the former only involves pointer operations.

Comment: @q0987:  Is that a question?  If so, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Just want to know the reason why you choose `vector<shared_ptr<LargeClass> >`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when storing a pointer or a reference to a vector element. There are certain operations that can invalidate those references, such as `push_back`, `resize`, etc. If the index is what you're sure will not change, then it would be the safest. Smart pointers, as marcin_j mentioned in the comment, will not help with the invalidation in case of push_back, resize, etc.

Comment: Since he's locating the element using an index to begin with, this is the obvious way to store the location.  Even if he were using iterators, however, `pos - vecLargeClass.begin()` would give him the insertion save index.